# Function for importing and plotting data from excel spreadsheet

Tags: plotting, import, excel

I know this must be a very basic question, but I could not find any answers. I need to create a function that: 1) imports data from an Excel Spreadsheet, 2) assign specific information from this xlsx file to variables and 3) plot this variables.

I wrote the function like this:

```
crindv[a_] := ({dados = Import[a]};{crpluscond= a[[1, Range[1,19], 2]], crminuscond = a[[1, Range[1,19], 3]]}; ListLinePlot[{crpluscond, crminuscond}, PlotMarkers->{}, PlotLegends->{"CS+", "CS-"}, FrameLabel->{"Condicionamento", "SCR (em \[Mu]S)"},Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, PlotRange->{{0,20}, {0, 1.5}}, FrameTicks-> {False, True}])
```

When I call this function,

```
In[36]:= crindv["/Users/pedrofonsecazuccolo/Dropbox/Doutorado/Piloto2/planejamento_e_analise/dados_para_mathematica/camila_mat.xlsx"]
```

the following error appears and Mathematica produces an empty graph:

```
During evaluation of In[36]:= Part::partd: Part specification /Users/pedrofonsecazuccolo/Dropbox/Doutorado/Piloto2/planejamento_e_analise/dados_para_mathematica/camila_mat.xlsx[[1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},2]] is longer than depth of object. >>

During evaluation of In[36]:= Part::partd: Part specification /Users/pedrofonsecazuccolo/Dropbox/Doutorado/Piloto2/planejamento_e_analise/dados_para_mathematica/camila_mat.xlsx[[1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},3]] is longer than depth of object. >>
```

I don't understand what is going wrong, since I am able to plot the same data by tipping the commands separately, like this:

```
In[27]:= dados = Import["/Users/pedrofonsecazuccolo/Dropbox/Doutorado/Piloto2/planejamento_e_analise/dados_para_mathematica/camila_mat.xlsx"];

In[28]:= Dimensions[dados]

Out[28]= {1,19,16}

In[32]:= crpluscond = dados[[1, Range[1,19],2]];
```

crminuscond = dados[[1, Range[1,19],3]];

```
In[34]:= ListLinePlot[{crpluscond, crminuscond}, PlotMarkers->{}, PlotLegends->{"CS+", "CS-"}, FrameLabel->{"Condicionamento", "SCR (em \[Mu]S)"},Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, PlotRange->{{0,20}, {0, 1.5}}, FrameTicks-> {False, True}];
```

Why does Mathematica not recognize the same dimensions of the data when it is imported using my function?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: a is the name of the Excel file not the data in the Excel  file. try change a to dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line of your code the variable a is assigned the string ["/Users/pedrofonsecazuccolo...."  and then trying to use the Part function that is a[[1,Range[1,19],2]] which indeed is a wrong part specification for the string.

Probably you intended dados[[1,Range[1,19],2]], which would take a Part from the data retrieved by Import[a] and assigned to dados.

OK?

Following your commments you may make following checks:

a) Did your replace in both assignments a with dados for crpluscond and for crminuscond ?

b) consider syntax for assigning the two variables crpluscond, and crminuscond as below

c) {dados=Import[a]} adds a depth to the array, not sure if required or not,  you may test removing the list brackets {}.

```
crindv[a_] := ({dados = Import[a]}; 
  crpluscond = dados[[1, Range[1, 19], 2]]; 
  crminuscond = dados[[1, Range[1, 19], 3]]; 
  ListLinePlot[{crpluscond, crminuscond}, PlotMarkers -> {}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"CS+", "CS-"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Condicionamento", "SCR (em \[Mu]S)"}, 
   Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 1.5}}, FrameTicks -> {False, True}])
```

PS: if these hints help you in finding a solution don't forget to vote for the penguins....

Comment: I have changed a to dados following @Algohi and your comment and now Mathematica will not return an error message. However, my function will not return any plot. When I call crindv["/Users/pedrofonsecazuccolo...."], Mathematica will return only out = crindv["/Users/pedrofonsecazuccolo...."]. Is there something else I should have added to my function code?

Comment: I corrected the synthax and now the function is working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: PS: I tried, but it appears I cannot vote because of my low reputation.